# Bad Access Code when connect to web with cUrl in c++

Tags: c++, curl, xcode5

When i put this code in main and put it static it works fine but when i separate them to another class. This problem comes out. Does anybody know why?

```
#ifndef __PathToExile__ConnectHandler__
#define __PathToExile__ConnectHandler__

#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ConnectHandler{

public:
    ConnectHandler();

    size_t data_write(void* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp);
    CURLcode curl_read(const std::string& url, std::ostream& os, long timeout = 30);
    void writeWebToFile(std::string filename);

};
#endif /* defined(__PathToExile__ConnectHandler__) */


#include "ConnectHandler.h"

ConnectHandler::ConnectHandler(){
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
}


size_t ConnectHandler::data_write(void* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    if(userp)
    {
        std::ostream& os = *static_cast<std::ostream*>(userp);
        std::streamsize len = size * nmemb;
        if(os.write(static_cast<char*>(buf), len)) //EROR: Thread 1: Exe_Bad_access (code = 1, address = 0x10)
            return len;
    }

    return 0;
}

CURLcode ConnectHandler::curl_read(const std::string& url, std::ostream& os, long timeout)
{
    CURLcode code(CURLE_FAILED_INIT);
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl)
    {
        if(CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &ConnectHandler::data_write))
           && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L))
           && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L))
           && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, &os))
           && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout))
           && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str())))
        {
            code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return code;
}

void ConnectHandler::writeWebToFile(std::string filename){
    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    if(CURLE_OK == ConnectHandler::curl_read("http://www.google.com", ofs))
    {
        std::cout << "Successfully write web to file " << filename << std::endl;
    }
}
```

So in the main file i call it like normal:
Connecthandler c()

c.writeWebToFile("haha-masupilami.txt")

the problem occur at function size_t data_write(..) i already comment the line problem occur. Does anybody know what went wrong. 'Cause it works file when i put i static function in main file.

Comment: `Connecthandler c()` doesn't define a variable of type `Connecthandler`. It declares a function taking no parameters and returning `Connecthandler`.

Comment: Make `data_write` static. `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` doesn't accept a non-static member function - it wouldn't know which object to call it on.

Comment: This shouldn't compile. You're passing a pointer to member function to `curl_easy_setopt` when you should probably be passing a pointer to function. Chances are the compiler is performing an implicit conversion to `void*` which would be a non-standard extension and in this case results in undefined behavior.

Comment: [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Ah. it makes sense. It Works now thanks you. you're savior

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Thanks. i change to static and it works.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: When i run this code. It does write to the file. But it hangs like it is waiting for st. Do you know why and how to stop this? it does not even run to the "successfully write web to file".